# applicability of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

Do all random variables dealing with number of random, independent events in a continuous interval follow a Poisson distribution?

Comment: No. $ $ $ $ $ $

Comment: The Poisson distribution has the property that the chance of an event in a time $\delta t$ is $\lambda\cdot\delta t$.

Comment: That is a somewhat vague way of putting it, which could probably be construed in ways that would amount to a false statement.  The things that are independent must be counts in non-intersecting subintervals. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: So where exactly can poisson distributions be used?